# Is it possible to have the debug.log on S3 bucket?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a wordpress website which runs on elastic beanstalk with 2 EC2 instances.  I would like to enable `WP_DEBUG_LOG` on the website. If i just enable the debugging the error log will write only on the ec2 which is currently serving the website to the user.

I already have an S3 bucket set and all wordpress uploads are being uploaded to this bucket. I would like to have the debug.log in a common place so both ec2 instances write in the same log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how we solved it, we wrote the log data to [Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/). It is a data firehose and firehose takes care of buffering it up and compressing it to S3. It can take from multiple producers and write it to the same destination.

Firehose organizes based on the timing and stores them in S3.
When you configure firehose select the destination to S3.

Image from the above Amazon Firehose Referenced link.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I am looking into Firehose and Wonolog with cloudwatch at the moment. Did you create a delivery stream? And what source did you choose, Kenesis stream or Source? Did you have to do any modification on wordpress to send every log through firehose?